# OR tag is not working with Cucumber Runner class

Tags: tags, cucumber

For some reason when i apply OR tags in Runner class it not working my console just print

```
0 scenarios
0 steps
0.01ms
```

**But when I provide individual tags then it works fine, can anyone provide timely help to fix this issue, please let me know what is missing here**

Feature file

```
Feature: Validate foreign exchange rates for positive and negative scenarios

  Scenario Outline: Verify rates for latest and past dated foreign exchange rates

    Given rates for foreign exchange rates
    When user calls Get http request with <Uri>
    Then user gets success with status code 200
    And <base> in response body is <baseValue>


    @Regression
    Examples: Positive scenarios
    |Uri            |base  |baseValue|
    |/api/latest    |base  |EUR      |
    |/api/2020-05-08|base  |EUR      |
    |/api/2010-01-14|base  |EUR      |      


 Scenario Outline: Verify the response from invalid url for 

    Given rates for foreign exchange rates
    When user calls invalid Get http request with <Uri>
    Then user gets error message with status code 400

    @NegativeTest
    Examples: Negative scenarios
    |Uri            |
    |/api/          |
    |/api/2020-02-30|
    |/api/20100114  |
```

Runner Class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features="src/main/java/features",//the path of the feature files
        glue= {"stepDefinitions"},//the path of the step definition files
        tags= {"@Regression,@NegativeTest"},**// this one is not working**
        //tags = {"@Regression"},   
        monochrome=true //display the console output in a proper readable format
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using? If you're on a recent version you can use `tags="@Regression or @NegativeTest"`. Otherwise you may have to try  `tags= {"@Regression","@NegativeTest"}`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using the latest version of cucumber and it doesn't recognize the old way of mentioning multiple tags.
For the mentioned example ,we can run both scenarios by mentioning tags = {"@Regression or @NegativeTest"} in runner class

(ie tags = {"@Regression,@NegativeTest") should be given as tags = {"@Regression or @NegativeTest"})

Also in the above query , i could see that tags are used above example keyword. Normally the tags can be used at the feature file level or before the scenario/scenario outline keywords